# Symfony2 how to structure a project when there is a lot of entity?

Tags: symfony, structure, project-organization

I have a project that is split in several parts, because i have a lot of entity(and all the controllers and forms which come with them), but they are in relation, and my question is, how do I have to structure my project does I need to have one bundle with several subfolder or several bundles because the best practice says that a bundle as to be independent and can be deleted, but the app still works. 
Thank you in advance and sorry for my low English level. 
The following diagram summarizes my question.

```
src/
AppBundle/
            Controller/
                        CustomerController/
                                        CustommerController.php
                                        ...
                        SaleController/
                        ...
```

or `src/ 
    CustomerBundle/
                Controller/
    SaleBundle/
                Controller/
    ...`

Best regards Toniouch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bundles, make them as small as they need to be. Having one, generic, tightly coupled bundle is a bad idea because it's hard to maintain as your app grows.

The recommended bundle structure is there for a reason! :)

More info on bundles here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html

Answer (score 0):

Symfony Best Practices: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html

Organizing Your Business Logic: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html

*Answer to your question:*

Entities: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#using-a-persistence-layer

Controllers: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html